# How to best encrypt data for sharing content via deep links or URLs?

Tags: json, security, web, url, encryption

Imagine a to-do list app in which we are trying to build a sharing feature. This particular list has the following data to be included in a URL to be shared.

1. List ID (20 char **string**)
2. Owner ID (20 char **string**)
3. Owner Type (short **string** or **int**)

This data can be displayed in JSON like:

```
{
  'lid': 'xxx...',
  'oid': 'xxx...',
  'type': 1,
}
```

The question: **How to encrypt this data into a secure string that will then be shortened with https://bitly.com/ and eventually be decrypted again to access this particular list by the client**

Ultimately we want to share a url like this one below

todolistapp.com/shorturl

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question seems to be its own answer. Encrypt the data. Put it in an URL in Base64url format. There is no step three. I probably would skip the JSON encoding step just to shorten the initial URL, but either way is fine. Is there something deeper to this question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I appreciate that. I thought it might be, I am curious about the different types of encryption and your suggestion about skipping the JSON encoding step to shorten the initial URL is helpful.

Comment: How to encrypt it depends on a lot of things. It's difficult, unfortunately, to give a single "here's how you encrypt, and it'll always be correct." I created RNCryptor to try to have a single "secure without thinking about it too hard" solution (https://github.com/RNCryptor). It's a reasonable starting point, but there are ways to make the output much shorter and faster for this particular setup (but that's more of a custom crypto-design problem, which is generally going to be something you get by hiring a consultant). For skipping JSON, I just mean "20 bytes, 20 bytes, 4 bytes" is shorter.

Comment: You can also of course encode as "length+string, length+string, fixed-length-int" if your strings tend to be shorter than 20 bytes. Designing a specific solution, again, is something you'd generally get through a consultant IMO. There's no simple "do this, and it'll be ideal." But relatively simple encodings (like "just glue the things together in order") should be straightforward.